# Integral of the product of the two functions (convolution)

Tags: convolution, poisson-process

I don't understand the result of this integral (in yellow). Could you help me please ?

[image]
Thank you !

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Learn the basics of Latex. Your first line for example is obtained by typing `$F^{n}(x)=\int_0^x F^{(n-1)}(x-y) dF(y)$` (in particular, all formulas are enclosed by dollar signs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just split it into two terms. For the first term note that $be^{-by}$ is the derivative of $-e^{-by}$. For the second term note that $e^{-by}e^{-b(x-y)}=e^{-bx}$.